# PHP ftp_put fails with "Warning: ftp_put(): PORT command successful"

Tags: php, ftp

File is created on the FTP server, but it's always 0 bytes large. Please give me a solution so that the file upload will working success.

I keep getting this warning:

> Warning: ftp_put(): PORT command successful in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mailing \ teskirim-file-simpan2.php on line 30
> FTP upload has failed!

[image]

My script is:

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "********";
$ftp_serverpath = "ftp.".$ftp_server;
$ftp_user_name = "********";
$ftp_user_pass = "***********";
$email_dir = "*******@*********";

$nyambungkeftp = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if (false === $nyambungkeftp) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
}

$loggedInnyambungkeftp =
    ftp_login($nyambungkeftp,  $ftp_user_name,  $ftp_user_pass);
if (true === $loggedInnyambungkeftp) {
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    throw new Exception('Unable to log in');
}

if ((!$nyambungkeftp) || (!$loggedInnyambungkeftp)) { 
        echo "FTP connection has failed!";
        echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
        exit; 
    } else {
        echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
    }

// upload the file
$dest = 'detectip.txt';
$source = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\persuratan\file2\detectip.txt';

echo $dest;
echo $source;
$upload = ftp_put($nyambungkeftp, $dest, $source, FTP_ASCII); 


// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
        echo "FTP upload has failed!";
    } else {
        echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
    }

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($nyambungkeftp); 

?>
```

Answer (score 22):

PHP defaults to the active FTP mode. The active mode hardly ever works these days due to ubiquitous firewalls/NATs/proxies.

You almost always need to use the passive mode.

For that call the [`ftp_pasv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) *after* the `ftp_login`:

```
ftp_pasv($nyambungkeftp, true);
```

See *my* article on [FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes), to understand, why you typically need to use the passive mode.

Answer (score 7):

Try two things:

1. Try FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII
2. Try to use passive mode doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked fine ... ftp_pasv ($ conn_id, true);

Comment: No problem, this is quite common issue. Please mark answer as accepted if you don't have any doubts.

Comment: How can binary mode help in this case?

Comment: This just change the way your files would be treated, so has influence on transfer. ASCII mode change EOL depending on OS. Binary mode don't change it just copy file as it is. ASCII mode could generate problem with data type like audio, images and so on. You can read more [here](http://www.jscape.com/blog/ftp-binary-and-ascii-transfer-types-and-the-case-of-corrupt-files)

Comment: Sure, it can corrupt binary files, but it cannot make the `ftp_put` fail!

Comment: You are completely right. Thank you for this comment and your article provided in answer. Your answer is better than mine because is based on deep knowledge and should be accepted, mine is based only on some experience in day by day work.